# Selenium finding elements from html then printing it. Python

Tags: python, selenium

Let's say I'm in a page and it has a span class called "someId", how do I search for this and get the Id that's in here.

```
<span class="someId">what is in here</span>
```

for example

```
<span class="someId">123456</span>
```

I want something that does this

```
element = driver.find_element('someId')
print(element) -> 123456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared I strongly believe the [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) `find_element_by_xpath("span[@class='someId']")` is **too broad** to identify an element **uniquely**. You may require to take help of a [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which identifies the *WebElement* uniquely. For that you have to traverse the *HTML DOM* a bit up to construct a *Locator* which uniquely identifies the element.

With the current *HTML* you have shared, to search for the *text* and print it you can use the following line of code :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("span[@class='someId']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with text mehtod which will return text with in that webelment

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("span[@class='someId']").text)
```